# Session and Cookie token are the same... is this a risk?

Tags: php, session, cookies, passwords, token

I have a login script that stores a hashed and salted token to a MySQL database on a successful login.  The raw token is then saved to a session variable, and optionally to a client cookie.

Is this a security risk?  Should I, instead, be storing the hashed token in my session, and only give the raw token by cookie?

Is there a better way in general to handle this scenario?

Comment: If the cookie accessible via javascript E.G not a secure cookie, it open to XSRF/XSS attack, if its not its open to mitm attacks and then session fixation, assuming you use the value as a kinda remember me. Encrypt a string like `RAND|IP|TOKEN|DATE_TIME|SESSION_ID|RAND` and store that decrypt and check that values match on subsequent yadas.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes regarding `Security` , choosing cookies is really a bad idea.

I hope you very well know that `cookies` can be easily tampered with. If you still want to store your raw token into `cookies`, whenever you do an operation , compare your `session` token and the cookie token, see if they match. If so, then do that operation. If they don't match, just expire the `session` (*i.e. logout the user*) and delete the `cookie`.

Comment: comparing tokens between database and cookie and deleting if they don't match is definitely done.  But you seem to be saying that cookies in general are bad.  How would you suggest implementing the industry standard "remember me" option?